# N- Level Hierarchy in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchy

i've N-level of categories in MySql..

```
id name parent
1  movie  0 
2  bollywood 1 
3  Hollywood 2 
4  Serial    0 
5  Star plus 4 
6  Sony      4
```

now i want to show in Movie Table like this

```
Tv Serial Name         Category

 Mahabharat            StarPlus-> Serial
```

how to show that ??

Comment: What have your tried?

Comment: You may want to read about [Managing hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the TV Series Mahabharat had the category_id 4.

Once you have that you can iterate through the categories until you find a category with the parent 0.

For example. :

```
public function getCategories($record)
{
    $category = "";
    $buildCategory = true;
    $id = $record['category_id'];

    while ($buildCategory)
    {
        $category = $this->getCategoryById($id); //Don't use query here, that's not efficient.
        if ($category['parent'] != 0) {
            $category .= $category['name'] . '->';
        } else {
            $category .= $category['name'];
            $buildCategory = false;
        }
    }

    return $category;
}
```

Comment: i think your code is corrent but what if i want to create it's function and use that function in all pages then how can i manage that ??

Comment: and where should i've to pass an Query...
ex:- select * from categories where id=$id
??

Comment: That would be in your getCategoryById function

Comment: dude...
i'm just beginner so i request you that you please mention that function also..

Comment: If you google a bit, you'll find plenty of PHP Tutorials that cover the basics of PHP like classes, functions, variabels..

Comment: dude..
i had created a function for that you please help me in that...

`function getCategoryById($id)
{
 $query="select * from categories where category_id=".$id;
 $res=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error);
 return $res;
}`

Comment: I highly recommend you reading through these chapters http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp They'll help you a lot in the understanding of how PHP works with MySQL.